Why am I getting 403 on GetAsync from api.stackexchange?
I am writing a demo app for myself to learn and suddenly I started getting 403 when doing api.stackexchange.com requests and I fail at EnsureSuccessStatusCode(). I'm doing them to populate my database with some tags data. (injected client just sets AutomaticDecompression to GZip)
public async Task<List<TagsImport>> ImportStackOverflowTagsAsync()
{
    var tagImportsList = new List<TagsImport>();
    var httpClient = _httpClient.GetClient();

    httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.stackexchange.com/");
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();

    for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        var response = await httpClient.GetAsync($"2.3/tags?page={i}&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=popular&site=stackoverflow");
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        var tags = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<TagsImport>(responseBody);
        tagImportsList.Add(tags);
    }

    return tagImportsList;
}

Tried manually testing the request and then testing previous versions of the app, the test in the app just returns "System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException : Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (Forbidden)." while manually writing "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/tags?page=1&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=popular&site=stackoverflow" in browser returns the data properly.
Am I missing something to make it work?

youre doing the api request in a loop here. does it fail on the first try or only in later ones?

Do you use an API key? Do you respect the backoff field (when it is not absent)? Try adding a small delay between the requests you make.

When your authentication fails according to the status code something is wrong with your authentication. And i don't see any in your code.

I want to use the API anonymously, I still have quota left and I'm doing max 10 requests per use. It also fails on the very first request. Don't really know how can I authenticate my app which runs only locally to use the stackexchange api then.

You definitely need to add the UserAgent Header, as one of the answers here points out. Otherwise a 403 is guaranteed. Then, you should check the has_more Property of the resulting JSON, to verify that you have more pages to get. Maybe, instead of a loop, increment a counter and bail out either if has_more = false or you have reached your goal. Add a Task.Delay(100) between calls to GetAsync() (or GetStringAsync() or GetFromJsonAsync<T>())

This error is caused by User-Agent header. Basically what you need to do is that add user agent header into your httpClient and it would behave like a browser getting the data without issues.
copy & paste this:
 httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.TryParseAdd("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36");

